# What is the fastest way to get beads?

Tags: bead-machine-punktasia

I am working towards getting the "You Win" badge which has the following requirement:

> Collect B180000000000T

This means I need to get 180,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 beads.  My best machine pumps out 128,000,000 beads every second.  Given that I am starting around 150,000,000,000 beads, then this means it will take about 1,406,249,999,998,829 seconds (44,591,894.98 years).

How can I get beads in a way that is not going to take several thousand millennia?

Comment: Does this game run in a browser? ♫

Comment: @badp yes it does

Comment: I think it's an invitation to cheat then :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speaks for itself i think, when it hits you generate 1.2 trillion triangles

[image]

Change last converter to a shuffler to get this for all income

Better design
[image]

Comment: This is insane.

Comment: although the screenshot was for triangles u just take the converter off for beads

Comment: By filling nearly the whole grid with uncoilers and puzzlers, I'm generating 10^31 coils.  If you want to generate comething other than coils, I recommend using a tranmuter and a dollars/beads/triangles loop on the bottom row before the shuffler.